# Does conflicted package prevent package installation?

Tags: r, installation, bioconductor, conflicting-libraries

I want to install a package from Github. **devtools** and **conflicted** packages are installed and loaded. So, when I run the code below:

```
devtools::install_github("david-barnett/microViz")
```

the output:

> Downloading GitHub repo david-barnett/microViz@HEAD
> These packages have more recent versions available.
> It is recommended to update all of them.
> Which would you like to update?
>
> 1: All
> 2: CRAN packages only
> 3: None
> 4: vctrs        (0.5.1      -> 0.5.2     ) [CRAN]
> 5: stringi      (1.7.5      -> 1.7.12    ) [CRAN]
> 6: magrittr     (2.0.1      -> 2.0.3     ) [CRAN]
> 7: glue         (1.5.0      -> 1.6.2     ) [CRAN]
> 8: cli          (3.5.0      -> 3.6.0     ) [CRAN]
> 9: colorspace   (2.0-2      -> 2.1-0     ) [CRAN]
> 10: iterators    (1.0.13     -> 1.0.14    ) [CRAN]
> 11: foreach      (1.5.1      -> 1.5.2     ) [CRAN]
> 12: crayon       (1.4.2      -> 1.5.2     ) [CRAN]
> 13: fastmap      (1.1.0      -> 1.1.1     ) [CRAN]
> 14: fs           (1.5.0      -> 1.6.1     ) [CRAN]
> 15: digest       (0.6.28     -> 0.6.31    ) [CRAN]
> 16: memoise      (2.0.0      -> 2.0.1     ) [CRAN]
> 17: cachem       (1.0.6      -> 1.0.7     ) [CRAN]
> 18: sass         (0.4.0      -> 0.4.5     ) [CRAN]
> 19: jsonlite     (1.7.2      -> 1.8.4     ) [CRAN]
> 20: htmltools    (0.5.2      -> 0.5.4     ) [CRAN]
> 21: Rcpp         (1.0.7      -> 1.0.10    ) [CRAN]
> 22: utf8         (1.2.2      -> 1.2.3     ) [CRAN]
> 23: fansi        (0.5.0      -> 1.0.4     ) [CRAN]
> 24: cpp11        (0.4.1      -> 0.4.3     ) [CRAN]
> 25: tinytex      (0.35       -> 0.44      ) [CRAN]
> 26: stringr      (1.4.0      -> 1.5.0     ) [CRAN]
> 27: bslib        (0.3.1      -> 0.4.2     ) [CRAN]
> 28: xfun         (0.28       -> 0.37      ) [CRAN]
> 29: highr        (0.9        -> 0.10      ) [CRAN]
> 30: evaluate     (0.14       -> 0.20      ) [CRAN]
> 31: rmarkdown    (2.11       -> 2.20      ) [CRAN]
> 32: knitr        (1.36       -> 1.42      ) [CRAN]
> 33: yaml         (2.2.1      -> 2.3.7     ) [CRAN]
> 34: pillar       (1.6.4      -> 1.8.1     ) [CRAN]
> 35: generics     (0.1.1      -> 0.1.3     ) [CRAN]
> 36: tidyselect   (1.1.1      -> 1.2.0     ) [CRAN]
> 37: tibble       (3.1.6      -> 3.2.0     ) [CRAN]
> 38: purrr        (0.3.4      -> 1.0.1     ) [CRAN]
> 39: dplyr        (1.0.7      -> 1.1.0     ) [CRAN]
> 40: RCurl        (1.98-1.6   -> 1.98-1.10 ) [CRAN]
> 41: permute      (0.9-5      -> 0.9-7     ) [CRAN]
> 42: viridisLite  (0.4.0      -> 0.4.1     ) [CRAN]
> 43: RColorBrewer (1.1-2      -> 1.1-3     ) [CRAN]
> 44: farver       (2.1.0      -> 2.1.1     ) [CRAN]
> 45: isoband      (0.2.5      -> 0.2.7     ) [CRAN]
> 46: gtable       (0.3.0      -> 0.3.1     ) [CRAN]
> 47: RcppArmad... (0.11.4.2.1 -> 0.12.0.1.0) [CRAN]
> 48: sp           (1.4-6      -> 1.6-0     ) [CRAN]
> 49: plyr         (1.8.6      -> 1.8.8     ) [CRAN]
> 50: igraph       (1.2.9      -> 1.4.1     ) [CRAN]
> 51: ggplot2      (3.4.0      -> 3.4.1     ) [CRAN]
> 52: data.table   (1.14.2     -> 1.14.8    ) [CRAN]
> 53: ape          (5.6-2      -> 5.7       ) [CRAN]
> 54: ade4         (1.7-18     -> 1.7-22    ) [CRAN]
> 55: tidyr        (1.1.4      -> 1.3.0     ) [CRAN]
> 56: backports    (1.4.0      -> 1.4.1     ) [CRAN]
> 57: TSP          (1.2-2      -> 1.2-3     ) [CRAN]
> 58: matrixStats  (0.61.0     -> 0.63.0    ) [CRAN]
> 59: png          (0.1-7      -> 0.1-8     ) [CRAN]
> 60: clue         (0.3-62     -> 0.3-64    ) [CRAN]
> 61: commonmark   (1.7        -> 1.8.1     ) [CRAN]
> 62: sourcetools  (0.1.7      -> 0.1.7-1   ) [CRAN]
> 63: fontawesome  (0.2.2      -> 0.5.0     ) [CRAN]
> 64: httpuv       (1.6.5      -> 1.6.9     ) [CRAN]
> 65: uuid         (1.0-3      -> 1.1-0     ) [CRAN]
> 66: htmlwidgets  (1.5.4      -> 1.6.1     ) [CRAN]
> 67: Rtsne        (0.15       -> 0.16      ) [CRAN]
> 68: broom        (0.7.10     -> 1.0.3     ) [CRAN]
> 69: seriation    (1.4.1      -> 1.4.2     ) [CRAN]
> 70: shiny        (1.7.1      -> 1.7.4     ) [CRAN]
>
> Enter one or more numbers, or an empty line to skip updates:
> checking for file ‘/private/var/folders/pv/2mldv52547j6ymmkpmcrmrv80000gn/T/Rtmpp9ZrBN/remotese89b1001745f/david-barnett-microViz-f4ac535/DESCRIPTION’ ...
> preparing ‘microViz’:
> checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ...
> installing the package to process help pages
> saving partial Rd database (18.3s)
> checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
> checking for empty or unneeded directories
> Removed empty directory ‘microViz/vignettes’
> building ‘microViz_0.10.8.tar.gz’
>
> system (cmd0): /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R CMD INSTALL
> **Error: could not find function "conflict_prefer"**
> Execution halted
> Warning message:
> In i.p(...) :
> installation of package ‘/var/folders/pv/2mldv52547j6ymmkpmcrmrv80000gn/T//Rtmpp9ZrBN/filee89b4f7f112e/microViz_0.10.8.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

I could not find much information on why this error occurs. I tried detaching conflicted, unloading it, installing package with other options. But same error occured. Weirdly, when I checked the issue on terminal as this:

`R CMD INSTALL --help`

> Error: could not find function "conflict_prefer"
> Execution halted

occured again.

Session info as following:

> R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31)
> Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
> Running under: macOS Monterey 12.6
>
> Matrix products: default
> LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib
>
> locale:
> [1] en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/C/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8

Installing from package archive file sometimes resolves the issue. Something like `conflict_prefer('install_github', 'devtools')`
does not help too.

My question is, what is going on here?

conflicted package has been installed and used frequently. Later, I needed to install new packages,  using BiocManager from GitHub. But this error occured and installation cancelled. Installing package from archive file worked sometimes. Changing R version was even more problematic, cause even archive file does not help and same I am getting the same error.

I would expect no issue to install packages, or a workaround to ignore or implement "conflicted" pacakge functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installation using devtools runs error for some reason. `Conflicted` package doesn't take a part in it. Accordingly to projects github https://github.com/david-barnett/microViz/ try to use:

```
install.packages(
  "microViz",
  repos = c(davidbarnett = "https://david-barnett.r-universe.dev", getOption("repos"))
)
```

This should work. It also requires installing dependencies which are listed on the page.